# border-box with percents and margins

Tags: border-box, css

how do you use border box with percentage and margins?
example follows.

```
<style>
.half{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    margin: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px black;
}
</style>
<div class="half">half</div>
<div class="half">half</div>
```

i want the div(.half) to take up 50% of the screen - a 5px margin all around the div is this posable every time i try it makes it wider than 50% and puts the second box on the next row i would like to avoid % based margins if posable.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

margins are never computed as part of the width, even using  `box-sizing: border-box;`

So try replacing margin with `border: 5px solid transparent`

---

Or, if you can't override borders, depending on the effect you want to achieve try with `:after/:before` pseudoelements, e.g.

```
.half {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px black;
}

.half:after, .half:before {
    content: "";
    width: 5px; /* or more if you need more space */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/imiqak/1/edit

---

Or you may use some nested elements, like so:

```
.half {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
}

.half p {
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px black;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/imiqak/3/edit

Comment: yeah i tried that but in my actual code trimmed down for example i am also using box shaddows

Comment: @MitchellBray then use `padding` instead of `border`. or use `:after/:before` pseudoelements inside `.half` elements (5px wide) if horizontal spaces are enough for your purpose

Comment: also transparent doesn't give the gap i am after.

Comment: could you please give an example of :after/:before pseudoelements

Comment: i have added an image to better describe what im after seems like its not posable without using % based margins though

Comment: then I suppose you have to use some nested elements, e.g. http://jsbin.com/imiqak/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

margin are considered as outside the box (it's spaces around your box, not in the box). Margins size are not counted as part of the container width.

Indeed, when you type `box-sizing: border-box;`, you means `the size of the box includes the border size`, and if you look at this image below, you'll see that the margin are after the border, so it's ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.half{
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.half:last-child{
margin-left: 1%;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="half">half</div>
<div class="half">half</div>
```

Comment: do you know of any way without % margins i would really like a set 5px margin